# Can someone explain parallelpython versus hadoop for distributing python process across various servers?

Tags: python, hadoop, parallel-processing

I'm new to using multiple cpu's to process jobs and was wondering if people could let me know the pro/cons of parallelpython(or any type of python module) versus hadoop streaming?

I have a very large cpu intensive process that I would like to spread across several servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since moving data becomes harder and harder with size; when it comes to parallel computing, data localization becomes very important. Hadoop as a map/reduce framework maximizes the localization of data being processed. It also gives you a way to spread your data efficiently across your cluster (hdfs). So basically, even if you use other parallel modules, as long as you don't have your data localized on the computers you are doing process or as long as you have to move your data across cluster all the time, you wouldn't get maximum benefit from parallel computing. That's one of the key ideas of hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that Hadoop is good at processing **big data** (dozen to terabytes of data). It provides a simple logical framework called MapReduce which is well appropriate for data aggregation, and a distributed storage system called HDFS.

If your inputs are smaller than 1 gigabyte, you probably don't want to use Hadoop.

Comment: Even a gigabyte is pushing it!

Comment: @orangeoctopus It really depends on what your are doing. For simple data aggregation, processing 1 gigabytes is a lot faster on one machine than on a Hadoop cluster. Fixed and transfer costs are huuuge.

Comment: That's what I meant. I wouldn't suggest using Hadoop until you reach 100's of GB, and even then there are likely better solutions.